# High response time from new StreamReader(webRsp.GetResponseStream())

Tags: asp.net, wcf, filestream, iostream

I am trying to get response from web url.

but while we are throwing some load on it, lets say 100 user load. this line of code work very slowly. After reading the response from below code I have to send myXML to calling function for some use.

```
using (StreamReader rspStr = new StreamReader(webRsp.GetResponseStream()))
{

     myXML = rspStr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}
```

Is there any way to get good response time even after throwing 100 or 1000 users load.

Comment: How is this related to WCF? Perhaps your server doesn't accept so many concurrent connections.

Comment: Server is accepting the concurrent connection, problem is with above code only.

Comment: how big are those files?

Comment: Those files having 100 KB Max data.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with an Async approach, just to avoid locking the execution on Stream opening or slow network waits, everything is explained here:

[Making Asynchronous Requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86wf6409.aspx)

snippet:

```
 WebRequest wreq = WebRequest.Create(httpSite);

      // Create the state object.
      RequestState rs = new RequestState();

      // Put the request into the state object so it can be passed around.
      rs.Request = wreq;

      // Issue the async request.
      IAsyncResult r = (IAsyncResult) wreq.BeginGetResponse(
         new AsyncCallback(RespCallback), rs);

   private static void RespCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   {
      // Get the RequestState object from the async result.
      RequestState rs = (RequestState) ar.AsyncState;

      // Get the WebRequest from RequestState.
      WebRequest req = rs.Request;

      // Call EndGetResponse, which produces the WebResponse object
      //  that came from the request issued above.
      WebResponse resp = req.EndGetResponse(ar);         

      //  Start reading data from the response stream.
      Stream ResponseStream = resp.GetResponseStream();

      // Store the response stream in RequestState to read 
      // the stream asynchronously.
      rs.ResponseStream = ResponseStream;

      //  Pass rs.BufferRead to BeginRead. Read data into rs.BufferRead
      IAsyncResult iarRead = ResponseStream.BeginRead(rs.BufferRead, 0, 
         BUFFER_SIZE, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), rs); 
   }


   private static void ReadCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   {
      // Get the RequestState object from AsyncResult.
      RequestState rs = (RequestState)asyncResult.AsyncState;

      // Retrieve the ResponseStream that was set in RespCallback. 
      Stream responseStream = rs.ResponseStream;

      // Read rs.BufferRead to verify that it contains data. 
      int read = responseStream.EndRead( asyncResult );
      if (read > 0)
      {
         // Prepare a Char array buffer for converting to Unicode.
         Char[] charBuffer = new Char[BUFFER_SIZE];

         // Convert byte stream to Char array and then to String.
         // len contains the number of characters converted to Unicode.
      int len = 
         rs.StreamDecode.GetChars(rs.BufferRead, 0, read, charBuffer, 0);

         String str = new String(charBuffer, 0, len);

         // Append the recently read data to the RequestData stringbuilder
         // object contained in RequestState.
         rs.RequestData.Append(
            Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rs.BufferRead, 0, read));         

         // Continue reading data until 
         // responseStream.EndRead returns –1.
         IAsyncResult ar = responseStream.BeginRead( 
            rs.BufferRead, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, 
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallBack), rs);
      }
      else
      {
         if(rs.RequestData.Length>0)
         {
            //  Display data to the console.
            string strContent;                  
            strContent = rs.RequestData.ToString();
         }
         // Close down the response stream.
         responseStream.Close();         
         // Set the ManualResetEvent so the main thread can exit.
         allDone.Set();                           
      }
      return;
   }
```

Comment: Here how to return response string to main function?